# My discord test bot returns 'You do not have the permission to use that command' even though I clearly have it on the channel for my role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm watching a youtube tutorial to try and make a bot for my discord server I think I'm having a problem with 'KICK_MEMBERS' because even though I have that permission, it returns 'You do not have permission to use that command'. Earlier, the error was that (hasPermission) is not a function. I'm mentioning this because maybe the tutorial video was just outdated. I'm not sure since it is returning the 'You do not have permission to use that command'. Maybe I'm missing something. What to do?

```
require('dotenv').config();

const {Client} = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });
const PREFIX = "y!";


client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`${client.user.tag} has logged in.`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    console.log(`[${message.author.tag}]: ${message.content}`);
    if (message.content === 'hello') {
        message.reply('konnichiwa');
        message.channel.send('mata konnichiwa');
        message.channel.send('konnichiwa');
    }
    if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
        const [CMD_NAME, ...args] = message.content
            .trim()
            .substring(PREFIX.length)
            .split(/\s+/);
        console.log(CMD_NAME);
        console.log(args); 

        if (CMD_NAME === 'kick') {
            if (message.member.permissions.has('KICK_MEMBERS')) 
                return message.reply('You do not have permission to use that command');
            if (args.length === 0) 
                return message.reply('Please provide an ID.');
            const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
            if (member) {
                member
                    .kick()
                    .then((member) => message.channel.send(`${member} was kicked`))
                    .catch((err) => message.channel.send('I do not have permissions...'));
            }   else {
                message.channel.send('That member was not found...');
            }

            
        }
        else if (CMD_NAME === 'ban') {
            if (message.member.permissions.has('BAN_MEMBERS'))
                return message.reply('You do not have permission to use that command');
            if (args.length === 0) return message.reply('Please provide an ID.');
            message.guild.members.ban(args[0]);
        }
    }
})

client.login(process.env.DISCORDJS_BOT_TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bot says `You don't permission to use this command` because you use:

```js
if (message.member.permissions.has('KICK_MEMBERS')) 
return message.reply('You do not have permission to use that command');
```

Which will only return if you **HAVE** this permission so you have to add `!` before `message.member.permissions.has`, like this:

```js
if (!message.member.permissions.has('KICK_MEMBERS')) 
return message.reply('You do not have permission to use that command');
```

Comment: Thank you, I got past that return function. Now I'm stuck in 'That member was not found. I tried putting ! before member (!member) but it says 
```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'kick')
```

Comment: @GenesisPineda `const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]).user`